# Downloading assets for pirate seas on pvz2

Tags: technical-issues, plants-vs-zombies-2

How do I download assets for the pirate seas level?. It always says to clear space on device, minimum of 510mb needed. My device has 522mb and its still not allowing me tp download the assets.

Comment: When you say mb, do you mean Megabyte (MB)?

Answer (score 0):

As it will download then extract them, you probably need *about* needed*2 of what it will download, however it will give back half of it after it installs it.